# Collapse Table Rows with JQuery by Default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rows

I implemented a method found on another Stack Overflow post to allow for the expanding and collapsing of table rows using JQuery. The approach is simple and works as expected, however I am encountering the issue that the rows are expanded by default. How can I make these appear collapsed on page load so that the user can decide which ones to expand?

As a side note, is there any way to make the collapse/expand appear more smoothly rather than just instant opened or closed?

Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function()
    {
        $('.header').click(function()
        {
            $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(1000);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr class="header">
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>meep</td>
        <td>meep</td>
        <td>meep</td>
        <td>meep</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
        <td>TEST</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>meep</td>
        <td>meep</td>
        <td>meep</td>
        <td>meep</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u81y5gzs/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5rrtqosh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This :-

```
$('table tr:not(.header)').hide();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u81y5gzs/)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Just out of curiosity as I have not seen this syntax before, how can I exclude multiple things? In my actual code I have a header row that is being hidden as well but would like to exclude that also. Thanks!

Comment: @BrettPowell...just visit the fiddle link i have mentioned in the answer ... i have already excluded the tr's with `.header` class as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$('.header + tr').hide();
```

[your working code](http://jsfiddle.net/5rrtqosh/)